# How to remove a drop of lasagna sauce on the white foam of sneakers / trainers?

Tags: cleaning, food, shoes, chemicals

I cooked last night and I’ve just realised today I got a drop of lasagna sauce on my trainers / sneakers.

I’ve tried removing it using a Dettol wipe, a rag soaked in isopropyl alcohol, and a cotton ear bud soaked in acetone (since that one’s usually pretty strong and sometimes eats plastic)… none of them have worked!

What can I do to remove this stain? Should I throw them in the washing machine without the soles?

[image]

Comment: Maybe with vinegar? Just speculating.

Comment: With bleach perhsps, starting tentatively with a mild dilution.

Answer (score 1):

Scrape off any excess sauce from the fabric or leather. Mix a solution of warm water and mild detergent. Dip a clean cloth in the solution and gently scrub the affected area of the shoe. Rinse off the cloth, then use it to wipe off the area and remove the detergent residue.

Answer (score 0):

Dilute some white vinegar (a ratio of about 1:3) add some dish soap. Just enough to get a foam...

Apply the mixture and leave it for about a minute then using a rag and some elbow grease it should come out.. You might need to repeat the process more than once.

A few tips..

- Don't scrub too hard you may damage the material.
- Don't soak or leave the mixture on the material as it is after all an acid and will eventually damage the material.

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt would be to use a "Magic Eraser." Please be sure to dampen the "eraser" with nothing other than water and wring out the excess. I cannot count how many times I've witnessed people trying to use a dry one.
No chemicals involved.